# how to separate a list and map from map item in dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I'm trying to separate a list from map item and also another map which is exist on my map item i'm beginner on dart?
someone help me how can do it?

Here is my list

```
  var studentList2 = [
{
  "Name": "Gias Uddin Samir",
  "Id": "110",
  "Result": [
    {"Phy": "3.0", "Che": "4.0"}
  ],
  "Completed": ["sp-2017", "sum-2017", "fall-2017"]
},
{
  "Name": "Gias Uddin Samir",
  "Id": "110",
  "Result": [
    {"Phy": "3.0", "Che": "4.0"}
  ],
  "Completed": ["sp-2018", "sum-2018", "fall-2018"]
},
{
  "Name": "Gias Uddin Samir",
  "Id": "110",
  "Result": [
    {"Phy": "3.0", "Che": "4.0"}
  ],
  "Completed": ["sp-2019", "sum-2019", "fall-2019"]
}
```

];

I want to separate Result list

```
      "Result": [
    {"Phy": "3.0", "Che": "4.0"}
  ],
```

ans also

```
      "Completed": ["sp-2019", "sum-2019", "fall-2019"]
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what the desired outcome is. Do you want to have all `result` and all `completed` in two separate lists. Do these have to just be one list of all distinct values?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe through the `map` method:

```
final results = studentList2.map((item) => item['Result']).toList();
print(results);
// [[{Phy: 3.0, Che: 4.0}], [{Phy: 3.0, Che: 4.0}], [{Phy: 3.0, Che: 4.0}]]
  
final completed = studentList2.map((item) => item['Completed']).toList();
print(completed); 
// [[sp-2017, sum-2017, fall-2017], [sp-2018, sum-2018, fall-2018], [sp-2019, sum-2019, fall-2019]]
```